React native paper dates DatePickerInput customization
I'm trying to customize DatePickerInput component from react native paper dates : https://web-ridge.github.io/react-native-paper-dates/docs/date-picker/input-date-picker
The component creates a clickable which opens a modal on click. I want to customize the modal: text color, background of the selected dates ...
Everything is in purple with the default theme.
I tried applying a lot of props including the theme prop:
<DatePickerInput
                  theme={{colors:
                  {
                    primary:"#4E73DF",
                    accent:"#4E73DF",
                    onSurface:"#4E73DF",
                    onBackground:"#4E73DF",
                    onPrimary:"#4E73DF",
                    surface:"#4E73DF",
                    backdrop: 'rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.2)',
                    onSurfaceVariant:"#4E73DF"
                  }}}
                  activeUnderlineColor="#4E73DF"
                  iconColor="#4E73DF"
                  locale="en"
                  label="Date de début"

                  style={{ backgroundColor: "white" }}
                  value={inputDate}
                  onChange={(d) => setInputDate(d)}
                  inputMode="start"
                />

Looking at the documentation / issues, but I cannot find something working for me.

the doc says that this can be done with PaperProvider : https://callstack.github.io/react-native-paper/docs/guides/theming/#extending-the-theme

the modal prop is set to a custom CustomModal component, which allows you to customize the styles and content of the modal.
import { Modal } from 'eact-native-paper';

const CustomModal = () => {
  return (
    <Modal
      contentContainerStyle={{ backgroundColor: 'white' }}
      style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}
    >
      {/* Your custom modal content here */}
    </Modal>
  );
};

<DatePickerInput
  modal={CustomModal}
  locale="en"
  label="Date"
  value={inputDate}
  onChange={(d) => setInputDate(d)}
  inputMode="start"
/>

